# Why this question didn't get any attention even after my edit?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked very much beautiful question: https://superuser.com/questions/1050126/how-to-remote-upload-the-torx-download-links

First moderators complained about unclear, so I edited it. still no reply or perfect answer came.

why so ?

Comment: "We do not support piracy"

Comment: What part of your question is not answered by the text in your image?

Comment: When [somebody says](http://superuser.com/questions/1050126/how-to-remote-upload-the-pcloud-download-links#comment1471335_1050126) "I am struggling to understand your question. Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to do?", and [you reply](http://superuser.com/questions/1050126/how-to-remote-upload-the-pcloud-download-links#comment1471708_1050126) "It is not that difficult to understand this post.", you are shooting yourself in the foot.  You *should* attempt to make your question clearer, and you ***should not*** insult people who might want to help.

Answer (score 2):

The first revision of the question was indeed very unclear, and it was appropriately put on hold. After your edit, I understand what you're trying to do, but there are still two problems:

1. Some people here frown on piracy. I don't know whether you're actually trying to do something shady, but many people are uncomfortable with questions asking how to circumvent DRM-ish things, even if those questions aren't off-topic.
2. More importantly, questions about specific web sites or services are off-topic here; we deal with only desktop software. I would close your question as "not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)."

Additionally, "please help me" generally makes people not want to help you. I suggest looking at highly-voted questions already on the site - especially ones written by experienced users - to see what a good question looks like. Do your best to adhere to professional English grammar and syntax, and remove all cruft (e.g. salutations, signatures).

Since you don't yet have the Informed badge, I will also direct you to [the tour](https://superuser.com/tour).